# "Error converting data type nvarchar to int." executing stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure and I am getting this error when executing it from C# code.

> Error converting data type nvarchar to int.

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[donateBloodProc] 
  @donorName varchar(50),
  @gender varchar(20),
  @email varchar(50),
  @bloodGroup varchar(50),
  @contact_number int, @L_D_D date,
  @city varchar(50),
  @arid_number varchar(50),
  @DepId int 
  AS
  INSERT INTO
        tblDonors(Dname, gender, bloodGroup, email, contact_number,
        L_D_D,city,arid_number,DeptID,dateDonated) 
    VALUES 
       (@donorName,@gender,@bloodGroup,@email,@contact_number,
       @L_D_D,@city,@arid_number,@DepId,GETDATE());
```

And this is my C# code:

```
SqlCommand commandForSP = new SqlCommand("donateBloodProc",DALobj.openConnection());
commandForSP.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@donorName", TextBox1.Text);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox5.Text);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bloodGroup", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_number", TextBox2.Text);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L_D_D", TextBox3.Text);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arid_number", TextBox1.Text);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepId", TextBox4.Text);

commandForSP.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

All the data types of the columns in my stored procedure are same as in my database table `tblDonors`

Comment: Another example of `AddWithValue` [causing problems](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 2):

as @bejger said it is because you are sending string instead of int to the contact and depid parameters.

but i think sending the `String/VARCHAR` value for `INT` columns is acceptable and it does not throw the exception if it is a valid integer.

it throws Exception when provided String can not be converted into Integer.
hence i would suggest you to use `Int32.TryParse()` method to perform the parsing before sending the value to the parameter.

`Int32.TryParse()` method returns true if the parsing is successfull otherwise returns false.

**Complete Code:**

```
if(!Int32.TryParse(TextBox2.Text,out var contact))
{
  //Error here you can return or display some warning
  return;
}

if(!Int32.TryParse(TextBox4.Text,out var depid))
{
  //Error here you can return or display some warning
  return;
}

SqlCommand commandForSP = new SqlCommand("donateBloodProc",DALobj.openConnection());
commandForSP.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@donorName", TextBox1.Text);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox5.Text);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bloodGroup", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_number",contact);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L_D_D", TextBox3.Text);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arid_number", TextBox1.Text);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepId", depid);

commandForSP.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with these lines:

```
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_number", TextBox2.Text);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepId", TextBox4.Text);
```

Because you try to pass string values, whereas your columns are of integer type. 
You should try to do this in such a way:

```
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_number", int.Parse(TextBox2.Text));
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepId", int.Parse(TextBox4.Text));
```

Although be aware that this is not fully error-proof (so if there is no value in the textbox it will throw an exception).

To summarize, your code will look like this:

```
SqlCommand commandForSP = new SqlCommand("donateBloodProc",DALobj.openConnection());
commandForSP.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@donorName",TextBox1.Text);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox5.Text);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bloodGroup",DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_number", int.Parse(TextBox2.Text));
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L_D_D",TextBox3.Text);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arid_number", TextBox1.Text);
commandForSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepId", int.Parse(TextBox4.Text));
commandForSP.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Also using `Int32.TryParse` would be better to see if these Text's are valid integer or not.